# Conditional probability without Bayes theorem

Tags: probability

If we have to find $P(A\mid B)$ - that is the probability of $A$ when $B$ is given - normally we find it using the Bayes theorem or by the formula

$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

I was wondering if the probability of $A$ when $B$ is given can be calculated as considering the sample space to be $B$ and then finding out the probability of $A$. It proved useful in certain circumstances. Is it correct? If yes then why are Bayes Theorem needed?

Answer (score 0):

This does allow you to calculate the value of $P(B|A)$, however, it's not at all clear how you'd do that calculation in general without Baye's Theorem. That is the right picture, and the answer to "so how do I calculate it" is Baye's Theorem